# Git commands executed by Intellij IDEA when updating the project and commiting changes

Tags: git, intellij-idea

We had some issues with our project due to automatic merging done by git. We don't directly use git commands and we make the commits through Intellij IDEA. It is much easier to use IDEA because our project consists of several modules which are in several git repositories and IDEA nicely handles changes done in all repositories.

My colleagues believe that we can avoid issues caused by git merging by manually doing git pulls, commits and pushes instead of use IDEA VCS features because they believe IDEA does some extra work behind the scene which causes incorrect merges.

Does IDEA do any extra work instead of issuing some git commands when it commits, pulls and pushes? Also is there a way to check what are the git commands issued by IDEA when performing a VCS task?

Comment: Your colleague is correct. IDEA performs some integration automatically for your files in your repo... for example, review the Version Control tab after you delete a file.

Answer (score 4):

The Console tab in the Version Control toolwindow shows exactly which Git commands are executed by the IntelliJ IDEA integration. It does not perform any Git repository modifications other than by running Git commands.